# Pentium 4 CPU not supported for upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade

I have a Laptop ASUS 2000, Pentium 4 CPU 3.00 GHz, 1 GB, Windows 7 Ultimate 32  bit. I can't upgrade to Windows 10 because my processor is not supported,  Windows says, although Windows 7 runs fine. Is there perhaps another solution to upgrade?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what CPU and motherboard we're talking about? "Asus 2000" doesn't seem to be a particular model of laptop.

Comment: Since this site won't let me respond with an answer, I can only add this comment here:

It is possible to bypass all the CPU checks to install and boot Windows 10 on an unsupported CPU. It is definitely not recommended, but if you are one of the crazy people like me, you can use the same method as Win8 to remove the CPU checks.

1. download Win8 no NX installation kit
2. make a new partition for Win10
3. extract the sources\install.wim file
4. ...ran out of characters...

Source: https://winclub.pl/topic/320-install-win8windows-81-on-cpu-without-nxpaesse2-support/

Answer (score 10):

No. The only solution is to get a newer laptop.

Background:  The pentium IV CPU is very old. Newer CPU has gained new features. One of those is the NX bit which is used to enhance security.

Windows 7 can optionally use this.
Windows 8 and later **require** it.

So to install windows 10 you need a CPU with this hardware part in the CPU. And as far as I know there are no CPU's which support NX which fit in a P IV socket.

---

Update and some relevant info:

- [what-is-pae-nx-sse2](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/what-is-pae-nx-sse2)
- [Here is aa list of Pentium 4 CPU's on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Pentium_4_microprocessors). Important to notice:
  Old P4's (Willamette core from  about 2000 and Northwood cores from 2002) simply do not have the NX bit.   More recent P4's (Presscott core from 2004-ish and later) do.
  If your CPU is new enough **and** you have a BIOS which supports it then you might be able to run windows 10 after all.
- Here is [someone claiming that NX is required to install, but possibly not used](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/windows-10-should-support-pcs-without-an-nx-bit/e84e1d67-0b17-487b-8c34-9ef128544909?auth=1) (in other words, it might run the OS if you patch   something))
- Power usage: P4 were notoriously power hungry. Depending on where you live it might make economic sense to dump the old P4 and replace it with something less power hungry.  This also depends on which P4 you have.

Comment: a patch can be used at your own risk http://catchtito.blogspot.de/2013/07/bypass-cpu-feature-checks-pae-nx-sse2.html

Comment: @GeorgeJansen - It **might** be possible to migrate to a Pentium D depending on several factors.  Pentium D and Pentium 4 share the same socket, the problem and one of those factors, is what the motherboard will support.  There was a significant change int he power requirements between Pentium 4 and Pentium D and most motherboards required a hardware revision update.

Comment: Aye. I should have thought of that since a pentium-D is more or less two P4's on a single chip.

Comment: While your answer may indeed the best recommendation, "No." does not accurately answer his question: "Is there perhaps another solution to upgrade?" as your post then goes on to suggest a possible solution (get a new laptop). It should also be added that another solution is to bypass the CPU requirements at his own risk.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer that the CPU is very old, but just for one last check you can go to the BIOS and make sure that you do not have the option to set the NX or XD flag in the BIOS.  Sometimes this is disabled.  Maybe you are lucky

Comment: I disagree. Some versions of the Pentium 4 did indeed support the NX flag, but some BIOS'es disabled this. The odds are against it, but I believe this could actually work and if it did, could allow installing Windows 10 on this ancient CPU.

Answer (score -1):

One solution could be to try to **upgrade the CPU itself**. Since you did not give the exact model (ASUS 2000 returns nothing), it's hard to tell if it is possible to do it, but it might. You would have to find out what the socket is, and try to get a second hand Pentium 4 with the NX bit, or even a Core Solo/Core Duo, Core 2 Duo. A BIOS upgrade might be necessary.

(On one of my laptops it was possible to upgrade the CPU from a Celeron M to a Core Duo with the NX bit. Those things come fairly cheap.)

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Pentium_4_microprocessors none of the mobile Pentium 4 chips supported NX/XD, and all used socket 478. The first mobile Intel chips to support XD were the Core Duo, as you noted, but use a newer socket M. Therefor there should be no CPU upgrade to support XD for his machine.